# Editable Div Element

Tags: jquery, xhtml, image, wysiwyg

Is it possible to have an editable div element that can only contain text and images.  I understand that you can use the rich controls like TinyMCE and jWYSIWYG however I do not require all this functionality and want something lightweight.

Basically all I want is a plain text editable element where I can also add various images such as emoticons that **can't be resized** when using IE or Firefox.  I am using jQuery as the framework so anything using that would be great.

**Update:**  Is it possible to block the click event for images so the resize handler doesn't appear?

**Related Question** [Firefox - designMode: disable image resizing handles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289433/firefox-designmode-disable-image-resizing-handles)

Comment: could you give a little more information? what are you using this for?

Comment: jmein, I have added more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can't force people not to resize images... I have an extension in Firefox that allows me to resize pictures no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally say something like TinyMCE is the best way to go.  You can disable a lot of the functionality you don't need, leaving you with just what you want.

Comment: The images are still resizable even within TinyMCE when using Firefox and IE and this looks plain dodgy.  Chrome doesn't let you resize them though.  I would have thought you could disable the image resizing.

Comment: Fix for the image resize in IE: Add this to your css: "img { -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic; }" (without the quotes). Source: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/12/22.html

Comment: Aaron, I don't want the images to be resized at all.

Answer (score 0):

This may have a little too much functionality as well, but I know that you can remove most of it. I dont think that images are resizeable once you put them in. It is kind of a web text editor. [CuteEditor](http://cutesoft.net/ASP.NET+WYSIWYG+Editor/default.aspx)

**Edit:** you can remove practically all functionality and can only allow text and images. It will have an html tab and another tab which you can also remove

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a simple and small [http://nicedit.com/index.php](http://NicEdit)

Comment: You can still resize images in this one when using Firefox.