# ASP.NET Telerik:Radeditor, disable image resizing on dragging

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radeditor

I just wanted to find out if it's possible to disable image resizing in the Design mode of the Telerik:RadEditor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image resizing is part of the browser's rich editing engine and AFAIK there is no code in the RadEditor to control it. You can try to find a general solution (e.g. [Firefox - designMode: disable image resizing handles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289433/firefox-designmode-disable-image-resizing-handles)) and apply it in the editor's content area.